# Internal JSON-RPC error code -32603

Tags: metamask, ethers.js

[image]

I'm encountering this error when calling a function that returns a string stored in the contract.

This is the ABI

{
"inputs": [],
"name": "getContractName",
"outputs": [
{
"internalType": "string",
"name": "",
"type": "string"
}
],
"stateMutability": "view",
"type": "function"
}

The weird thing is I have another contract in the project that also has a function that returns a string stored in the contract and that one does not trigger the error when calling it, its ABI being identical to what's above.
I am on the right network, and if I take the variable in which I store the contract and log it in the console, I can see that it contains the problematic function. I also succeed to call a function that returns a bool on this contract.
What additional information should I provide to figure this out? Thanks for dropping by ^^

Comment: The code of `getContractName` would be nice to look at. How are you testing? ganache, public testnet, private testnet. Is the abi and address correct? If you rename the function does it work? How long is the string returned? How do you make the call to the function?

Comment: @Ismael
function getContractName() public view returns(string memory) {
        return contractName;
    }
I am using Ganache to test it.
The ABI is:
{
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "getCourseName",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    },
The address is correct as far as I have checked.

Comment: The function is a simple getter defined by me, but I also have the generated getter to the public marked attribute of the contract I need and both lead to the error.  I am using etherjs to make the call(I have also opened an issue on their github). The string I am trying to receive back is 4 letters long.

Comment: The function is `getContractName` but in the abi it is `getCourseName`, are you sure it is the right abi?